# How to find ion/water channel related genes

Tags: molecular-biology, bioinformatics

We now have a collection of transcripts at hand. We would like to investigate some particular ones, which are ion/water channel related. How to perform this? Could anybody point out how to find the annotated genes those are ion/water channel related? If there are some places particularly for fish, that would be perfect. Thanks.

Comment: In case you don't know it, this should be of help: http://www.geneontology.org/

Comment: i'm afraid a literature crawl is the only reliable way to get domain knowledge like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to blast your transcripts against the [TCDB](http://www.tcdb.org) which has all ion channel templates you can get in the literature. Second best would be to blast against a general protein database like UniProt.